# Timer that runs in the background in Python 3.7.0

Tags: python-3.x, timer, python-multithreading

I am trying to make a timer in my text-based adventure games so that for every second that passes, 1 hp is taken away from the user, *while* they are in a certain scenario *and* can still use other functions. Here's my code:

```
#Imports and base variables
import time
import threading
import random

hp=100 #Health

p="snow" #Starting point

invtry=[] #Inventory of Character

#Function to drop health
def hlthdrp():
    hp-1
t=threading.Timer(1.0,hlthdrp)
t.start()
while p=="snow" or p=="Snow":
        if hp==0 and p=="snow" or p=="Snow":
            print ("You died of frostbite")
            t.cancel()
            threading.wait(timeout=5.0)
```

As of right now, I'm not getting any errors, but instead, a completely blank shell, or terminal. If anyone could help, that'd be great!

Answer (score 0):

You must call threading.Timer recursively else it only calling one time

And you can use lower() function to compare snow or some string

There is your fixed code i hope it will be usefull for you.

```
def hlthdrp():
    global hp
    print(hp)# just for testing 
    hp=hp-1
    if hp!=0:
        threading.Timer(1, hlthdrp).start()

hlthdrp()
while p.lower()=="snow":
        if hp==0 :
            print ("You died of frostbite")
        elif hp!=0 :
            pass
```

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry but the way your code is formatted, it only drops the health, and it does not allow for any other input while that runs in the background, and if the health drops to zero, it loops "You died of frostbite".